# Expresión regular que empiece con mayúscula y acabe en punto

Tags: javascript, regex

Estoy empezando con expresiones regulares y no sé cómo resolver ésta. Se trata de hacer un patrón en JavaScript que empiece en mayúscula y acabe en punto. Este es el código que tengo hecho por el momento:

```js
function validarFrase() {
    var frase = document.getElementById("frase").value; 

    var reg=new RegExp("^[A-Z]+[.]$"); 

    if (frase.match(reg)){
        alert ("El formato es el correcto");
    } else {
        alert ("El formato es incorrecto"); 
    }

}
```

```html
Escriba su frase<input type="text" id ="frase"/>
<button onclick="validarFrase()">Verificar</button>
```

El caso es que meto un nombre, por ejemplo, "Paco." que cumpla los requisitos de la expresión regular y no me hace match, porque la expresión regular está mal, pero no sé como hacerla bien. ¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Comment: ¿ Y qué debe haber entre la mayúscula inicial y el punto final?

Comment: Para otra vez, las preguntas de regex **SIEMPRE** deben incluir los casos validos e invalidos....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intenta con esta expresion:

```
/^[A-Z][a-z]+[.]$/
```

Esta indica lo siguiente:

1. `^[A-Z]` : que comienze con 1 letra en mayuscula
2. `[a-z]+` : que contenga 1 o mas letras en minuscula.
3. `[.]$` : que al final del texto tenga el caracter punto ( `.` ).

Ejemplos:

```js
console.log("Hola.".match(/^[A-Z][a-z]+[.]$/)) // da match
console.log("HOla.".match(/^[A-Z][a-z]+[.]$/)); // no da match
console.log("HOLA.".match(/^[A-Z][a-z]+[.]$/)); // no da match
```

---

En caso de que quieras saber porque tu expresion falla es debido a que espera que el inicio del string tenga 1 o mas letras en mayuscula y que luego tenga el caracter literal `.`.

Esto indica que el texto *HOLA.* dara match mientras que *Hola.* No.

En escencia:

1. `^[A-Z]+` : que comienze con 1 o mas letras mayusculas
2. `[.]$` : que al final del texto tenga un punto ( `.` ).

Comment: Técnicamente no se ha mencionado que el segundo y siguientes caracteres tengan que ser letras minúsculas, ni que tengan que ser uno o más. Habría que saber si cadenas como "PA." o "P." son válidas ya que ambas empiezan en mayúscula y acaban en punto.

Comment: no entiendo porque no dan match las tres.. si cumplen con que empiezan en mayuscula y terminan en punto...

Answer (score 6):

Si debe de empezar con mayúscula y terminar en punto y todo lo que está entre ellos puede ser minúscula o mayúscula o número, puedes usar esta expresión regular.

`^[A-Z].*[.]$`

Por ejemplo:

```
"Paco."  ---->  # Emparejará. 
"Padsdo." ----> # Emparejará.
"PASDFDcvcv." ----> # Emparejará.
"Wdfdfdfd123g." ----> # Emparejará.
```

Si deseas que sólo vaya letras, entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, puedes usar la siguientes expresión regular.

`^[A-Z][A-z]+[.]$`

En donde te emparejarán tipos de esta clase.

```
"Paco."    
"PAco."
"PACO."
"PasdsdsdDcoc."
"RdcdfgfDDDDDDc."
```

Espero haya podido ayudarte.

Comment: +1 :) yo reemplazaría `[.]` por `\.`, ya que la última es más fácil de leer (no sabía hasta recién que el punto dentro de un grupo no necesita ser escapad)

Answer (score 3):

Ofrezco una opción sin usar expresiones regulares, esto le dará menos complejidad a tu código

```js
function validarFrase(){
  let str = document.getElementById("frase").value; 
  let formatoCorrecto = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase()  == str.charAt(0)&& str.slice(-1) == ".";
  console.info("formato correcto?", formatoCorrecto)

}
```

```html
Escriba su frase<input type="text" id ="frase"/>
<button onclick="validarFrase()">Verificar</button>
```

Comment: Si esto fuera a formar parte de una aplicación de verdad, esta es la respuesta correcta. Si se puede hacer sin regex de una forma sencilla, no usemos regex :)