# Expresion Regular para evaluar si el primer caracter es mayuscula

Tags: javascript, java, groovy

Estoy iniciando con el tema de expresiones regulares y necesito evaluar si el primer caracter de una cadena es mayuscula. No es relevante conocer si los caracteres del resto de la cadena son mayusculas o minusculas.

Comment: Buenas! Qué has intentado hacer? Te recomiendo leer [ask] y agregar un [example]. Googleando encontré la misma pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317512/expresi%C3%B3n-regular-que-empiece-con-may%C3%BAscula-y-acabe-en-punto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Expresión regular que empiece con mayúscula y acabe en punto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/317512/expresi%c3%b3n-regular-que-empiece-con-may%c3%bascula-y-acabe-en-punto)

Comment: Esta respuesta en realidad es un comentario o debe de añadirse a la pregunta como aclaración

Answer (score 1):

Según lo que solicitas, la expresión regular que buscas es esta:

```js
var reg= new RegExp("^[A-Z]"); 

console.log("minuscula", "minuscula".match(reg))
console.log("Mayuscula", "Mayuscula".match(reg))
```

Donde `^` indica el inicio de la expresión, con corchetes indicas un rango `[]`, en este caso de la A a la Z (si buscas minúsculas seria [a-z]). En internet se encuentra mucho material sobre este tema.

Te recomiendo investigar primero un poco por tu cuenta antes de recurrir a foros.

Te adjunto una web donde puedes ir escribiendo y verificando tus expresiones regulares en tiempo real:

https://regexr.com/

Comment: Si la respuesta aclaró tu duda y te ayudó a resolver tu problema, márcala como aceptada. Espero haberte sido de ayuda.

Comment: De acuerdo a la [documentación del método `.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#descripci%C3%B3n), "Si se necesita saber si una cadena coincide con una expresión regular RegExp, use RegExp.prototype.test().". El OP no menciona que vaya a hacer algo con los resultados de la evaluación, solo que quiere saber si coincide o no, por lo que creo que sería mejor `const reg = /^[A-Z]/; console.log("minuscula", reg.test("minuscula"));`